# Can my landlord add additional fees for items listed as included in my rent?

Tags: tenant, human-rights, fees, virginia, lease-renewal

I live in Virginia,USA and I have been in my apartment for 3 years and each year when I sign my lease for renewal it states that my washer and dryer fees are included in my rent if applicable. The front office clerk placed an additional $40 on my rent for the month of November. I had my washer replaced because it stopped working.

When I inquired about the fee the office stated that I hadn’t paid for my washer and dryer since June 2022, but each renewal clearly states that it’s an included fee and not separate from my monthly rental payment of $1600.

Can the landlord add the additional fee to my rent on top of the $1600 when my renewals that have been signed by myself and the landlord show that the washer and dryer rental is already included?

Comment: wasn't this asked some weeks ago already?

Comment: https://www.valegalaid.org/issues/housing/landlord-and-tenant-issues